# Yammer login with access token

Tags: yammer

I'm making use of the Yammer APIs and embed feed. I was wondering if it was possible to force a sign into Yammer using the user's access token (saved in some local storage). Is it possible to make the yam.getloginstatus() function return true with just the access token, instead of having the user login every time?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [setAuthToken()](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askyammer/2016/11/04/preauthorizing-the-yammer-js-sdk/) method available which can be used to inject a token. You can continue to authorize a user to your Yammer app and store the token, or use the more advanced approach with impersonation as laid out in the article that is linked. Make sure to create threat models for your application so you have a plan to protect user tokens.

Comment: Hi Brian. Thank you for the response. I tried using setAuthToken() method in the following way `yam.platform.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    if(response.authResponse) {
        alert(response + "1");
    }
    else {
        console.log(response + "2")
        yam.platform.setAuthToken("auth_token");
        console.log(response + "3");
    }
});`

When I do so during initialization, it gives me the 502 error when trying to load the embed feed. Any ideas about how to fix this?